# Android device name->maker mapping

Tags: data-request

An Android "device name" is an identifier of a particular model. Each device announces its model as a string. Examples of "device name" strings:

```
Dell Dell Streak 7 (streak7)
hltexx
Toshiba Corporation AT10LE-A/AT15LE-A/AT10PE-A/AT15PE-A  (Japan: AT703) (tostab12BA)
highscreen_Zera_S
Samsung Galaxy S3 (m0)
bq_Edison2_QuadCore_3G
Foxconn International Holdings Limited IN810 (VKY)
504
```

I have identified [9295 Android device names](https://gist.github.com/nicolas-raoul/e17696c9f032f63d53cf) strings.

I am trying to find more information about what devices output these names, in particular the maker.
For instance, `Samsung Galaxy S3 (m0)` -> `Samsung`

Is there a database which references these names, mapping each one to a particular maker?
Bonus if it also maps to other information like hardware specifications.

Answer (score 1):

This list from Google has devices that support Google Play, and are grouped by manufacturer. The list is updated regularly. Unfortunately, it's a PDF - [LINK](https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/D9E52CEA2646E4F148A1B29C7C839C628B61).

[image]

One option to make the data more machine readable is to convert to TXT with pdftotext - [raw text](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=CUWE30Y4)

```
pdftotext -layout devices.pdf
```